# Extension of holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be a simply-connected domain in $\mathbb{C}$, and $A$ be a closed simply-connected set such that $A\subset \Omega$ and $\Omega\setminus A$ is connected. Let $f$ be a holomorphic function in $\Omega\setminus A$. It is true that $f$ can be extended to meromorphic function $g$ in $\Omega$ ?

Comment: Generally, no. Try to find (simple) counterexamples.

Comment: @DanielFischer, right. Assume that $g$ can have only isolated singularities (essential, pole, removable). It is still false ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $\Omega$ to be the whole of the complex plane, and $A$ to be the complement of the unit disk. There are functions that have the unit circle as natural boundary. For example, the function  $1+z+z^2+z^4+z^8+z^{16}+\cdots$ does not extend to any open set containing the unit disk.